# compareandexchange() vs compareandset() of Atomic-Integer

Tags: java, atomic, java-9, compare-and-swap, atomicinteger

While working on AtomicInteger, I found this API provides two Methods.

**compareAndExchange**:

> Atomically sets the value to newValue if the current value, referred
>   to as the witness value, == expectedValue, with memory effects as
>   specified by `VarHandle.compareAndExchange(java.lang.Object...)`

**compareAndSet**:

> Atomically sets the value to `newValue` if the current `value == expectedValue`, with memory effects as specified by
>   `VarHandle.compareAndSet(java.lang.Object...)`.

I am unable to understand difference between two, Please help with suitable example.

Answer (score 13):

The two methods have a different return type.

`compareAndSet` returns `boolean`:

> true if successful. False return indicates that the actual value was not equal to the expected value.

`compareAndExchange` returns an `int`:

> the witness value, which will be the same as the expected value if successful

i.e. `compareAndSet` indicates whether the value of the variable was updated, while `compareAndExchange` returns the current value of the variable, which gives you more information.

`compareAndSet(1,2)` will set the value of the atomic integer to `2` if the previous value was `1`, and will return `true` in that case. Otherwise, it will not set the value, and it will return `false`.

`compareAndExchange​(1,2)` will set the value of the atomic integer to `2` if the previous value was `1`, and will return `1` in that case. If the previous value wasn't `1`, it will not set the value, and will return the current (unchanged) value.

Comment: But they both are using different memory instructions - that is COMPARE_AND_EXCHANGE and COMPARE_AND_SET will that make any difference in the reslut

Comment: @Eran Why would `compareAndExchange​(1,2)` return 1 if the previous value was 1. Shouldn't it return the *current value* which would be 2?

Comment: based on the following discussion, CAS could be faster than CAE: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8141640