# What is the difference between the 'Compare And Swap' and 'Compare And Set' operations?

Tags: java, algorithm, assembly, compare-and-swap

I'm trying to understand the 'Compare And Swap' operation, briefly called CAS. I found that it has a variant called 'Compare And Set'. They work the same way but the return is different. 'Compare And Swap' returns a value but 'Compare And Set' returns a boolean.

My question is whether they use the same Compare And Exchange (`CMPXCHG` for x86) instruction on low-level. Are they both implemented by atomic classes in Java ?

Comment: Easy to simulate compare-and-set with compare-and-swap but not vice versa. Suspect that Java omitted compare-and-swap for portability, but that it's implemented with CMPXCHG on x86 (that being the most obvious way to do it).

Comment: BTS is a test and set instruction on x86, but it's only for bits. It does work with the LOCK prefix for atomic functionality.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: The question of portability came up again recently, as BeeOnRope pointed out in an answer on [Why does std::atomic\_compare\_exchange update the expected value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77533925) that C++11's `compare_exchange_strong` would need a loop (if the updated value of the `expected` reference arg is used) on hypothetical hardware that only made a boolean status available on failure, not the old value.  Maybe Java architects were less confident in the non-existence of such hardware than the C++ committee?

Comment: @PeterCordes hmm, actually, does LL/SC (on the relevant architectures) give you the old value typically?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Yes, you load-linked into a register, compare-and-branch to skip the store (and clear the "monitor") if the compare doesn't match, then run a store-conditional (and branch back to the start on spurious failure, unless you're doing `CAS_weak`.)  LL/SC is usually only found on RISC machines, so a memory-source compare wasn't an option in the first place, you have to load into a register even if later code doesn't use the updated `expected`.  e.g. AArch64: https://godbolt.org/z/1zadn9ez5 (where seq_cst just uses special instructions, not separate barriers.)

Comment: (GCC doesn't run `clrex` after skipping the `stlxr` but clang does. https://godbolt.org/z/d7TaMnovj  I think it's expected that OSes will avoid spurious success on context switches between LL/SC pairs by doing `clrex` if necessary, so I think clang is over-cautious.  Newer gcc / clang for AArch64 call a library function if it can't inline ARMv8.1 single-instruction atomics so we can't see if that code-gen changed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a wrapper that exposes the functionality of x86 `lock cmpxchg` or equivalent [compare-and-**swap**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) instructions / sequences on other ISAs.  But Java's old `compareAndSet` API only returns the boolean success, not the old value on failure, so there are things it can't quite do.

A recent question, *[Java 8 impl on Compare And Exchange (Not Compare and Set!)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73349502)* was about emulating Java17 `compareAndExchange` (returning the old value) in terms of Java `compareAndSet` - it can't be done precisely.  You can load a value from near the time of the exchange, but it might end up the same as the "expected" arg to your CAS even if your CAS failed.  But if you keep both the boolean and the value you read separately, that's fine for most algorithms.

This situation is like [GNU C's old `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html) vs. `__sync_val_...` for cases where you did want the old value.  The latter is more powerful: you *can* get success/fail from the `val` version by comparing the return value yourself.  So it's a bit disappointing that Java would provide only the less powerful one from Java 8 until Java 17, although it is the one that a lot of algorithms would be more likely to use.

(GNU C later added `__atomic` builtins that match the C++11 API of `compare_exchange_weak` with a bool return value and the first arg by reference, updated on CAS failure.  So you get either or both, depending on which outputs you bother to actually use.)

Also related:

- [compareandexchange() vs compareandset() of Atomic-Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648557/compareandexchange-vs-compareandset-of-atomic-integer)  explains how they're very similar, differing only in return value.
- [How does "Compare And Set" in AtomicInteger works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634280/how-does-compare-and-set-in-atomicinteger-works)